# Let m = $min(\omega_1)$. Show that {m} is clopen in $\omega_1$

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

> Let $(W, \leq)$ be an uncountable well order, then $\omega_1 = \{\alpha \in W: pred(\alpha)$ is countable } where $pred(\alpha) = \{y \in W: y < \alpha \}$

I have a couple of thoughts and I was hoping for some feedback: 1. $\omega_1$ is Hausdorff and so singletons are closed. 2. $pred(m)$ $\subseteq \omega_1$ and since $\{m\}$ is $min(\omega_1)$ it follows $pred(m)$ $\subseteq$ $\{m\}$, so $\{m\}$ contains all of its limit points and hence is closed. 3. Consider $\omega_1 \setminus \{m\}$ then this set has a minimal element, since it is a subset of a well order which is again a well order. Denote this by $m + 1$. Then $\omega_1 \setminus \{m\}$ = $[m + 1, \infty)$ which is closed in $\omega_1$ and hence its complement $\{m\}$ is open.

Comment: $\min\omega_1=0$. What do you actually intend $m$ to be?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott W can be any uncountable well-ordered set, why is min$(\omega_1)$ = 0 ?

Comment: Because $\omega_1$ is a specific ordinal whose least element is the ordinal $0$. $W$ is completely irrelevant.

Comment: complement,not compliment .  May be just a typo.

Comment: It’s not in general true that $\omega_1=\{\alpha\in W:\operatorname{pred}(\alpha)\text{ is countable}\}$. What *is* true is that $\omega_1$ is order-isomorphic to that set; is that what you’re supposed to prove? And once again, your $m$ makes no sense.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott We haven't explicitly constructed $\omega_1$, we have only defined it as a subset of an uncountable well-order and we are working with it only via the properties it satisfies

Comment: So you're defining $\omega_1$ not in the usual way but in terms of an otherwise unspecified uncountable well-order $W$. As long as you're using unorthodox notations, why not introduce the notation 0 for the first element of $W$? Then your notation gets close enough to standard for Brian's comments to be useful. In particular, $m$ is a single element of $W$ and $\text{pred}(m)$ is empty.  You haven't specified a topology, but if you're using the order topology then $\{m\}$ is both open and closed.

Comment: I'm using the order topology, how is it both open and closed ? Thank you !!